# find specific element with numpy in 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I need your help, I am new to Python so I need to search an array for a specific value in the first column and return the text found in the second column.

```
dataProject = np.array([
    [1]['text 1'],
    [2]['text 2'],
    [3]['text 3'],
    [4]['text 4'],
    [5]['text 5']
])

a = np.where(dataProject[:,0].astype(int) == 2)
print(a)
```

in the example it would have to return "text 2", but it returns

```
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: Not sure how you're constructing that array, would assume its meant to be: ```np.array( [[[1],['text 1']],
[[2],['text 2']],
[[3],['text 3']],
[[4],['text 4']],
[[5],['text 5']]])```

Comment: In the example above, ```dataProject``` cannot be interpreted as a variable. But this task seems to trivial to implement with an array, wouldn't it be better to use a hash-map?

Comment: if @jojo_040 suggestion is correct, then you want to index the second column with the value where the first column is equal to ```'2'```, note that 2 is a string. ```dataProject[:,1][dataProject[:,0] == '2']```

Comment: @Kevin python doesn't have hash-maps (like java) - but I suppose you mean Dictionary? Yeah that would work too (deff more efficient for this purpose)

Comment: @jojo_040 Yes, thank you, dictionary is the correct term. Python seems to have no distinction between ordered and unordered maps. But in any case the lookup time complexity will be much better - O(1) compared to O(N).

Comment: Given this exact input a simple `dict(map(lambda e: (int(e[0]), e[1]), dataProject.squeeze()))` would convert the nested array to a dictionary (int -> str)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you intended to have a 2D array, i.e. dataProject.ndim = 2, the following line of code returns *all* values of the second column for which the first column is equal to 2.

```
dataProject = np.array([[1, 'text 1'],
                        [2, 'text 2'],
                        [3, 'text 3'],
                        [4, 'text 4'],
                        [5, 'text 5']])

a = dataProject[dataProject[:,0].astype(int) == 2, 1]
```

In this case `print(a)` will print `['text 2']`. As the comments mentioned, if there should be a unique key-value mapping, then a Dict would be a better choice. If you want only the first instance instead of a list of strings, you could `print(a[0])` or do `a = dataProject[dataProject[:,0].astype(int) == 2, 1][0]`.